# What kind of problem in quantum mechanics can have an algebraic method of solution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For example, a harmonic oscillator can have an algebraic solution, and  hydrogen potential can
also have an algebraic solution. Here the algebraic method of solution means that we can use the similar methods like $a$ and $a^\dagger$ to solve QM problem. So in general what kind of problem in QM can have an algebraic solution. For example, can infinite potential well have a algebraic solution, and so on.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, for "algebraic solution"?

Comment: My remark/question above is due to the fact that for the harmonic oscillator it is clear what algebraic could mean: the procedure relying upon $a$ and $a^\dagger$. Also for the hydrogen potential (reducing to the previous case), but I do not understand in what sense the infinite potential case should admit an "algebraic" solution.

Comment: @V.Moretti I mean that we can use similar methods like $a$ and $a^\dagger$ to solve a QM problem

Comment: Which type of QM problem? This question (v2) seems to be a list question and quite broad.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11975/2451

Answer (score 3):

When the system is a [many-body system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-body%5fproblem), it can't be solved analytically. Unlike classical mechanics, for $N = 3$ or $N = 4$ ([few-body systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Few-body%5fsystems)), there do exist [Faddeev equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%5fequations) which can be solved by iteration. There should be more factors that I don't know.

P.S. Here is a [incomplete list of those systems with analytical solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List%5fof%5fquantum-mechanical%5fsystems%5fwith%5fanalytical%5fsolutions).